# Will removing Empathy (for Pidgin) break my desktop integration?

Tags: empathy, pidgin

The question ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62664/how-can-i-remove-empathy-and-integrate-pidgin)) answers the question about whether or not Empathy can be replaced with Pidgin.

What it *doesn't* answer is whether or not removing Empathy (via Software Centre) will break Ubuntu 11.10 because of the obvious integration (like statuses in messaging menu).

I prefer Pidgin's (more accurate) notifications to Empathy's, hence the desire to change.

Can I safely remove Empathy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can safely remove Empathy. It will not break anything also remove whatever leftovers Empathy leaves.

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanted Empathy back, then would it install everything as if were never removed to begin with? (Such as the messaging menu extras.)

Comment: Yes just Install Empathy from the Software Center and it will pull back whatever was installed by *default*.

Answer (score 1):

no i have removed but nothing happened but no need to remove empathy to have desktop integration with pidgin.

i had this somewhere on internet and it worked like a charm for me :
 sudo apt-get install pidgin ( if not installed)

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-pidgin
- sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool ( if u have not installed aldready)

open advance setting in gnome shell and just make sure that the pidgin-integration-extension in shell extension is in on position. if it is in on then every thing going to be fine as it is not supported on some gnome-shell , i f it is not in on position or if is somewhat like disabled or  if u are not able to toggle it to on/off position then i think integration will not be possible(not sure)  , try to update ur system and try again.

if the pidgin-integration-extension is running fine i.e. it is on position then :

press alt + f2 then type r and press enter or just log out and log in to restart shell

remove empathy : sudo apt-get purge empathy ( not necessary )

*note : to avoid getting both the standard Pidgin notifications and the new ones, in Pidgin select Tools > Plugins and uncheck the box next to "Libnotify Popups".